# how to send a dummy date to api server

Tags: java

Stack Overflow experts!

I am a coding beginner who is currently studying coding at an academy. Our team is attempting to clone Stack Overflow, and we are  in the process of building the project. We are using Spring Boot, Java 11, JPA, and Gradle.

Here's the problem! The frontend team has requested dummy data so they can test their work. I have written the following code in the HomeController/

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/api/dummy")
    public JSONArray getData() throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Reader reader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/dummy/dummy.json");
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea how to connect the frontend page to this data. Please note that the dummy data is in the form of objects for posts, answers, member information, and comments.

What should I do in this situation?

THANK YOU! IN advance!! please help me ....

i tried to use this query .. but nothing happened .

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/dummy",
            success: function(response) {
                const forumData = response[0].forum;
                const forumListElement = $("#forumList");
                for (let i = 0; i < forumData.length; i++) {
                    const forum = forumData[i];
                    forumListElement.append("<li><a href='/question/" + forum.id + "'>" + forum.title + "</a></li>");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *"but nothing happened"* - Now is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors at all on the browser console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  If so, what is the server's response?  When using the script debugger to step through the code, what specifically happens?

Comment: Instead of saying "but nothing happened" (because that tells us nothing), focus on what _did_ happen. Did the request get through to the server? Did the server's endpoint code run correctly? Did it send the correct response? Did the response make it back to the browser (viewable via the browser's network debugging tool)? Was the response a fully-formed 2XX response? Did your `success` code throw an exception somewhere?

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with using jQuery in this context, but is the URL of the request supposed to be relative?

Comment: An aside: never use paths that are IDE-bound. Real Java has nothing to do with your IDE upon deployment. If the json's a resource, read it as one, else read from a known safe location (somewhere in `user.home`)

Comment: You need some console.log() and System.out.println() to see haw far it’s getting. Does it make the jquery call? Does the call reach the Controller? Does the response get back to the page. Collect that info and add to the question.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, in code, _something_ always happens. Your job when debugging code is never to figure out why _nothing_ happened, but to figure out why _what you expected to happen_ didn't happen. And uncovering what _actually_ happened is key to figuring that out.